# Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module> EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python

so i was trying to building a simple guessing game then when i tried it, it gave me this error "Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 5, in  EOFError: EOF when reading a line"

```
     secret_word = "Adam Omar"
     guess = ""

     while guess != secret_word:
         guess = input("enter your guess:")

     print("you win!")
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. It works fine for me. Please provide more details. OS, python version etc.

Comment: i use windows 10 pro and my python version is python 3.8 the app i use is PyCharm
here is its link
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows